# ASP.NET timed Label Display

Tags: asp.net, c#-4.0, timer, label

I am new to ASP.NET. I made a simple application which performs some of the mathematical operation like addition, subtraction and so on. Now I have many Labels for each output(add, sub, multiply) . Now I want to display label(add output) first and then after 5 second I want to display next label and so on......

Can anyone help me out. Thanks.

Comment: What about using a timer or sleep methode?

Comment: There is no "sleep mode" in ASP.NET. It's RESTFUL Http!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First hide all the labels except 'ADD' using

```
$("#labelId").hide(); \\do this for all the labels except Add label
```

then

```
$("#labelAdd").delay(800).show(); \\give the delay as you like in milliseconds 
$("#labelSub").delay(800).show();     
$("#labelMul").delay(800).show();
```

Give a reference to jQuery library in `head` section then,
Put these scripts inside `<script>` tag inside

```
$(document).ready(function(){
//above code here.
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You should definetly read some javascript or I would totally recommend [jQuery](http://www.jquery.com), [jQuery delay](http://api.jquery.com/delay/) and [jQuery show](http://api.jquery.com/show/). Those are the 3 things you need.

You hide your label with some css `visibility:hidden` or `display:none` and then you can show it delayed with `.show()` from jQuery.

Have you done anything with javascript/jquery so far? need more help?

Comment: No i have not work with jqeury before. just know js little bit. Can we do in some other way using C#

Comment: No please. If I say I recommend it, then you should take the step and just do it. There is a very ugly and hard way to do it with some kind of javascript tools from microsoft, but you really want to do this with jQuery! Paste your code so I can help you getting this done.

Comment: I have tried to use the Thread.Sleep() method.but it is not working

Comment: Shall I explain this in general to you or won't you read that aswell? Just do it with Javascript. With pure asp.net it's **not possible!!**

Comment: var no1 = Convert.ToInt32(TextBox1.Text);
            var no2 = Convert.ToInt32(TextBox2.Text);
                this.result = no1 + no2;
                Label4.Text = Convert.ToString(this.result);
                //Thread.Sleep(100000);
                this.result = no1 - no2;
                Label6.Visible = true;
                Label6.Text = Convert.ToString(this.result);
                this.result = no1 / no2;
                Label8.Visible = true;
                Label8.Text = Convert.ToString(this.result);